# How to authenticate the client service when using CAS in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas

I have created CAS server and the CAS Client application. Basically the authentication of a service app has been done using service ticket and proxy ticket validation. In this case, initially I validate a particular user by validation of the service ticket and then authorize a user for a particular app by generating a proxy ticket using the service ticket. In this case I am able to successfully validate the service and proxy tickets in the service application. The problem that I am facing is that once I validated the user I can retrieve the user information via Assertion object using the following code segment.

```java
Assertion assertion = serviceTicketValidator.validate(serviceTicket);
```

Here the `serviceTicektValidator` object is a class that I have written by implementing the `Cas20ServiceTicketValidator` valdation functions. Here the assertion object is set to the `SecurityContextHolder` as follows.

```html
CasAssertionAuthenticationToken token = new CasAssertionAuthenticationToken(assertion, serviceTicket);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
```

Here this way, I am setting the authentication object. But the fact is once the request is changed or consider a new request, in the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` filter class in the following code segment the `SecurityContext` object is being cleared. So once a new request is fired the already stored authentication detail is vanished from the `SecurityContextHolder` object. So once every request the authentication details has to be set, because a particular service or proxy ticket can only be validated once. Here the approach taken by me is keeping the `Assertion` object and ticket generated in the Session and then at the beginning of this class (or actually I am doing all these in a filter) I check whether these values are in the session and again at each new request the `CasAssertionAuthenticationToken` is set to the `SecurityContextHolder`.

```html
 HttpRequestResponseHolder holder = new HttpRequestResponseHolder(request, response);
        SecurityContext contextBeforeChainExecution = repo.loadContext(holder);

        try {
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(contextBeforeChainExecution);

            chain.doFilter(holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());

        } finally {
            SecurityContext contextAfterChainExecution = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            // Crucial removal of SecurityContextHolder contents - do this before anything else.
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            repo.saveContext(contextAfterChainExecution, holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());
            request.removeAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED);

            if (debug) {
                logger.debug("SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed");
            }
        }
```

The application is working the expected way, but I want to know whether there is a better way to implement this by using advanced techniques in Spring Filters or any other option. I also considered local storage of tickets and authentication information, but I want to do this within Spring Application even without using this session storage mechanism. I want to know whether this is possible or not?

Comment: You are correct. You should cache the authenticated user in the HttpSession. Remember that the container uses a ThreadPool. This means that if request a (coming from user a) sets the SecurityContextHolder with user a's Authentication and does not clear it out. Later request b (coming from user b) would be authenticated as user a which is wrong.

Comment: @RobWinch Thanks a lot for this reply. I want to know what is the best practice that we should be taking when working with Angular2 and CAS. How to keep these service tickets or proxy tickets in the client applications. Is Spring Session with Redis a better solution or is there any better way. I am currently designing a complete flow and I have already completed CAS related Server and Client basic configurations. Please guide me to improve my application with better development standards.

Comment: You should use a session cookie and allow the browser to maintain the cookie. If you need a distributed session, then Spring Session is a good choice.

Comment: @RobWinch Thank you very much. Do you have any clue on the structure of the angular2 application. what I mean is how to manage the user details the best way in angular2 app. I want to learn best practices. Is there any good references or guidelines for Spring - Angular base applications. Thanks a lot for your time.